# Centering site on mobile (android)

Tags: jquery, mobile, centering

I'm using this code to center my site on a desktop computer web browser:

```
  //Always center content in browser window
  $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#wrapper').css({
      left: ($(window).width() - $('#wrapper').outerWidth())/2,
      top: ($(window).height() - $('#wrapper').outerHeight())/2
    });
  });

$(window).resize(); // To initially run the function
```

It works great but not on an Android smartphone; it gets stuck on the upper left corner. Here's the [link](http://www.novaplaquemar.pt/index_exp.html).

Is there any "common-usual" code to achieve this?

Comment: You're aware that, at least in Chrome, it says `left:0px; top :0px;` and that it's not actually doing any positioning, right?

Comment: But it's centering on desktop computer browsing - shouldn't it also be mis-aligned here as well?

Comment: @Pedro I suspect it has to do with your positioning CSS. top, bottom, left, and right are all 0.

Comment: You should refrain from using javascript when you can use css to achieve your goal.

Comment: I excluded the jQuery part and applied **margin: auto 0px;** to the #wrapper - same result though.